# Не запускается nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. У меня не запускается nginx. При попытке запуска пишет такое:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() «/var/log/apache2/domains/isp.devpl.net.error.log» failed (2: No such file or directory) nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

ОС - Ubuntu 14.04

**Обновление**

Проблема решилась с помощью `mkdir -p /var/log/apache2/domains/`, но появилась другая.

У меня nginx работает в связке с apache. Если запустить nginx - не запустится apache, говорит, что занят порт (насколько я понимаю). Если запустить apache (остановив nginx) - не запустится nginx - тоже говорит, что занято, а конкретно:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 192.168.1.205:80 failed (98: Address already in use) nginx: [emerg] bind() to 192.168.1.205:80 failed (98: Address already in use) nginx: [emerg] bind() to 192.168.1.205:80 failed (98: Address already in use) nginx: [emerg] bind() to 192.168.1.205:80 failed (98: Address already in use) nginx: [emerg] bind() to 192.168.1.205:80 failed (98: Address already in use) nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Comment: Разделяй и влавствуй! 80 порт для nginx, а 8080 порт или какой другой для apache

Comment: разобрался, уже запустились. но по ходу у меня потерялась привязка сайтов. какой бы я не открыл - пишет @It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что нет файла isp.devpl.net.error.log или директории domains в конфиге nginx-а.